# TabLayout setupWithViewPager bug

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-pageradapter

I have an example activity on which I'm adding 50 Fragments to a ViewPager. When I tap on a tab (from TabLayout), this one becomes underlined. It's the default behaviour.
[image]

Inside the Fragment, I have a button, Close, which calls mAdapter.remove(position); and here comes the problem, because I'm getting:
[image]

So, the current Fragment, is 46, which is right, but even if I set up with setupWithViewPager() - and so there is a listener which should automatically do it - after closing test45, the tab test46 is not shown automatically with its underline. Why? To me it seems related to something inside calculateScrollXForTab(...) at line 418 in TabLayout.java, but maybe I'm simply wrong.

I made a public repository with this example, so you can try it on-the-fly: https://github.com/MyWay/TabLayoutBug

Comment: Well, I can tell you that I can reproduce your problem, and that the `demo` app from CWAC-Pager does not exhibit the same problem. I bumped the page count to 50, swiped (painfully...) over to page 45, deleted it, and `PagerTabStrip` handled it fine. So, I agree that the problem lies in `TabLayout`. I'd [file a bug report](http://b.android.com) if I were you. However, change your `build.gradle` to use `url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"`, as you get an SSL error with what you have in the sample app now.

Comment: Bug report filled out! https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219976